# Grep not stopping

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm quite new to bash/shell scripting and can't seem to figure this out. While executing a bash script it stalls on a grep command. The Terminal just stops doing anything and you have press CTRL+Z to stop the script. I do not see a problem with the command line itself.

Code:

```
DATE="01-Apr-14"

grep 'error' | grep -v 'PHP Notice\|PHP Warning\|File does not' ~/Desktop/Servers/Folder/Error/Error_$DATE.txt >> ~/Desktop/Review/Folder_Review_$DATE.txt
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What file is the first grep looking at?

Comment: The command is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: It's stalling because it's waiting for input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed grep orientation:

```
 grep 'error' ~/Desktop/Servers/Folder/Error/Error_$DATE.txt| grep -v 'PHP Notice\|PHP Warning\|File does not'  >> ~/Desktop/Review/Folder_Review_$DATE.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

`grep 'error'` is expecting its input from *standard in*. If you're not providing any input (via the keyboard, a pipe, etc), then it will block indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Your first grep is reading `stdin`. I think you wanted

```
grep 'error' ~/Desktop/Servers/Folder/Error/Error_$DATE.txt | \
  grep -v 'PHP Notice\|PHP Warning\|File does not' \
  >> ~/Desktop/Review/Folder_Review_$DATE.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Try pressing Ctrl + c.

It worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33087071)

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl + D` will send an EOL symbol.

This helped for me.